# SQL Trigger on field update to insert new record in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to keep a record of changes to data in a table. I've read there are various ways of doing this that sound a lot more convenient, but in my situation i want to do implement this functionality using a trigger. I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Applications
(
  Application_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Student_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Job_ID INT NOT NULL,
  ApplicationChange_TYPE VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (Application_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students(Student_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Job_ID) REFERENCES Jobs(Job_ID),

  CONSTRAINT CK_TYPE CHECK (ApplicationChange_TYPE in ('Submitted', 'Withdrawn', 'Invited For Interview', 'Invited to Assessment Centre', 'Rejected', 'Accepted'))
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE ApplicationChanges
(
  ApplicationChange_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Application_ID INT NOT NULL,
  ApplicationChange_TYPE VARCHAR(64),
  ApplicationChange_DATETIME DATE NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (ApplicationChange_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Application_ID) REFERENCES Applications(Application_ID),

  CONSTRAINT CK_APPTYPE CHECK (ApplicationChange_TYPE in ('Submitted', 'Withdrawn', 'Invited For Interview', 'Invited to Assessment Centre', 'Rejected', 'Accepted'))
);
```

I would like to create a trigger so that when the ApplicationChange_TYPE field of a record in the Applications table is edited/updated, a new record is created in the ApplicationChanges table. I need it to carry over the Application_ID and ApplicationChange_TYPE from the edited record in the applications table in to the new record in ApplicationChanges. The ApplicationChange_DATETIME field should be populated with the current date.

At current, the primary keys of both tables use a sequence and trigger to auto ID number on the creation of a new record.

Any input would be much appreciated! And apologies if i've been at all unclear.

EDIT:

Also i have already made an attempt at this, but i'm so unsure of it and it seems so broken that i didn't think there was any point in including it. But here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ApplicationsUpdateTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON Applications
BEGIN
  INSERT ApplicationChanges (Application_ID, ApplicationStatus_TYPE, ApplicationChange_TYPE)
  SELECT Application_ID, ApplicationStatus_TYPE FROM Applications
    JOIN inserted ON inserted.Application_ID = Applications.Application_ID
  INSERT INTO ApplicationChanges (Application_ID, ApplicationStatus_TYPE, ApplicationChange_DATETIME)
  VALUES (NULL, Application_ID, ApplicationStatus_TYPE, GETDATE())
END;
/
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Why a "sequence and trigger" instead of "sequence and column default"?

Comment: There's nothing in the question that states the questioner is using SQL Server/TSQL so I've rolled back those tags.

Comment: It's how our lecturer has suggested we do it. I guess because the project is based on representing the use/understanding of triggers and sequences.

Comment: I am working in Oracle SQL Developer. Apparently i need more influence to edit the tags and people have made edit suggestions so i just approved them, assuming they were right.

Answer (score 0):

I'll stick with Oracle as the question tag says (though using GETDATE() in your sample trigger suggests SQL Server).

I'm not sure which ApplicationChange_TYPE value you want to store in ApplicationChanges table: the one before change (old one) or after change (new one)?

Let's cover both variants, assuming sequence and trigger for auto incrementing id columns works fine.

1. THE OLD VALUE:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ApplicationsUpdateTrigger
   AFTER UPDATE ON Applications
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     IF (:OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE IS NULL AND :NEW.ApplicationChange_TYPE IS NOT NULL) -- this one is actually redundunt as long as you've got NOT NULL constraint on Application.ApplicationChange_TYPE column
        OR (:OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE <> :NEW.ApplicationChange_TYPE)
     THEN
       INSERT INTO ApplicationChanges (Application_ID, ApplicationChange_TYPE, ApplicationChange_DATETIME)
       VALUES (:OLD.Application_ID, :OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE, sysdate);
     END IF;
   END;
   /
   ```
2. THE NEW VALUE:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ApplicationsUpdateTrigger
   AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT  ON Applications
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     IF (:OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE IS NULL AND :NEW.ApplicationChange_TYPE IS NOT NULL) --this check is not redundant (:OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE will be NULL on inserts)
        OR (:OLD.ApplicationChange_TYPE <> :NEW.ApplicationChange_TYPE) 
     THEN
       INSERT INTO ApplicationChanges (Application_ID, ApplicationChange_TYPE, ApplicationChange_DATETIME)
       VALUES (:NEW.Application_ID, :NEW.ApplicationChange_TYPE, sysdate);
     END IF;
   END;
   /
   ```

Differences are quite cosmetic: the second variant works on both UPDATE and INSERT and uses :NEW record values instead of :OLD ones.